# C# Windows Service using reflection for plugin assemblies

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies

I am writing a windows service that can transfer files using various method i.e email, ftp.
Each file or fileset can have their own configuration details.

For every file or fileset that need to be delivered after being generated I want to create an assembly that can be drop in a folder and the service will pick it up on the next scheduled run. This assembly make use of a standard interface defining the delivery methods of the file or filesets. These plugin assemblies might need to reference other dependent assemblies i.e. external ftp library or email library that need to be included in the folder as well where I have to drop the plugin assemblies.

**My question:** Is there a way of ignoring the dependent assemblies in the folder where the plugin assemblies will reside? Or are there a way of organizing the plugin assemblies in one folder and their dependent assemblies separately?

Here is my code where the service loop through the assemblies. Currently it will use everything that is in the folder and will probably throw an exception:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssemblyStorage"])))
{
      var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);

      Type type = assembly.GetType("ReflectionTest.Plugin");

      if (type != null)
      {
          object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
          var resultFtp = type.InvokeMember("FTP", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null,obj, null);
          var resultEmail = type.InvokeMember("Email",BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,null, obj, null);

          Console.Write(resultFtp);
          Console.Write(resultEmail);

          obj = null;
      }

      assembly = null;
      type = null;

}
```

**Plugin assembly:** The compiled plugin dll will eventually reside in the above mentioned folder - `(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssemblyStorage"])`. These plugin assembly file names can be anything.

```
namespace ReflectionTest
{
    public class Plugin : ITransferService
    {
        public bool FTP()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool Email()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a perfect candidate for MEF. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx

Comment: Why not introduce a convention on the name of the plugin's assembly. This way you will be able to filter out the dependent assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1. You can mark your plugin assembly with a special attribute and then check it before enumerating all types.To put an attribute on an assembly, in any code file of that assembly you can write:

```
[assembly:YourSpecialAttributeClass]
```

Option 2. You can also try separating assemblies in different folder, and hooking into AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event, manually searching for needed assembly in plugins and dependencies folder.